# Converting from .asm to .s file (Windows/Intel)

Tags: mips

For my homework, I had to write a MIPS program. I'm on windows/intel machine and used notepad++ to write it, which doesn't have the functionality to save the file using a .s extension. Is there any way to save the file as a .s using windows?

Comment: I always thought that before learning some programming languages you have to have at least basic user experience with the computer and it's software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Save As dialog, switch the "Save as type:" drop-down from "Text Documents (*.txt)" to "All Documents (*.*)" and type the full name of your file (e.g. "myfile.s").